# Azure DevOps Pipelines PowerShell task - how to catch any info from RetryHelper

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to use info from RetryHelper set in Control Options in Azure DevOps Pipelines PowerShell task.

Example of retry visible in console:

##[warning]RetryHelper encountered task failure, will retry (attempt #: 2 out of 3) after 4000 ms

Already tried:

- Get-Variable
- $warnings
- Get-ScheduledTask

I didn't find a single information.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Automatic retries for a task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-195-update#automatic-retries-for-a-task),

> There is no information about the retry count made available to the task.

So there seems to be no built-in way to directly access `RetryHelper` information from within a PowerShell task. The `RetryHelper` warnings you see are not something accessible from within the task script.

If you need to use the retry count, you can write a loop in your PowerShell script that retries the command a certain number of times before failing.

Example script ：

```
$maxRetries = 3
$retryInterval = 4000 # in milliseconds

for ($i = 1; $i -le $maxRetries; $i++) {
    try {
        # Your command here
         Write-Host "Hello World"
         Write-Host "this is #$i try"
         
        # If the command is successful, break out of the loop
        break
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Attempt #$i failed. Retrying in $($retryInterval / 1000) seconds..."
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $retryInterval
    }
}

if ($i -gt $maxRetries) {
    Write-Error "Maximum number of retries reached. The operation failed."
}
```